# How to communicate between two components with no parent-child relationship?

Tags: angular, angular-material

The `app.component.ts` is the entry point of my Angular 2 app. It holds two components: a header and a [sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-header></app-header>

    <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Here's what I want to achieve: Inside the `<app-header>` component I have a (menu) button, that should trigger the opening of the `<app-sidenav>` component.

In other words, a click event on the button in the `<app-header>` should trigger the `open()` method inside the `<app-sidenav>` component.

- **header.component.ts**:

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    template: `
      <button (click)="onSidenavOpen()">Menu</button>
    `
  })
  export class HeaderComponent {
    constructor() { }

    onSidenavOpen() {
      // trigger the opening of the <app-sidenav> component
    }
  }
  ```
- **sidebar.component.ts**:

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-sidenav',
    template: `
      <md-sidenav #sidenav>
        // bla bla, sidebar
      </md-sidenav>
    `
  })
  export class SidenavComponent {
    constructor() { }

    open(sidenav) {
      sidenav.open();
    }
    close(sidenav) {
      sidenav.close();
    }
  }
  ```

I read the [component interaction section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#) in the Angular 2 docs, but I am struggling to find the best approach to communicate between these two components. The general intention I have is to encapsulate as much logic as possible for each component.

How would you approach my use-case? Would you create an intermediate service? Please share an example.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service (don't ask why the caption says "Parent and children communication". Using a service is for component communication, no matter how they are or are not related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a service to allow two separate components to talk to each other. In the example below, the `HeaderComponent` pushes a value to an exposed `Observable` with the `toggleSideNav` method of the `SidebarService`. The `SidenavComponent` subscribes to this `Observable` on its initial load and will respond to a new value being pushed through.

**SidebarService:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"

import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class SidebarService {

    private sidenavOpenSubject : Subject<boolean>;

    constructor() {
        this.sidenavOpenSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
    }

    toggleSideNav(opening: boolean): void {
        this.sidenavOpenSubject.next(opening);
    }

    onSideNavToggle(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.sidenavOpenSubject;
    }

}
```

**HeaderComponent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  template: `
    <button (click)="onSidenavOpen()">Menu</button>
  `
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(private sidebarService: SidebarService) { }

  onSidenavOpen() {
    this.sidebarService.toggleSideNav(true);
  }
}
```

**SidebarComponent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  template: `
    <md-sidenav #sidenav>
      // bla bla, sidebar
    </md-sidenav>
  `
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private sidebarService: SidebarService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sidebarService.onSideNavToggle().subscribe(
            (opening) => {
                if (opening) {
                    //Logic to open the sidenav here
                } else {
                    //Logic to close the sidenav here
                }
            }
        );
    }

    open(sidenav) {
        sidenav.open();
    }

    close(sidenav) {
        sidenav.close();
    }
}
```

The `SidebarService` needs to be registered in a suitable module (e.g. your `AppModule`).

Comment: Note: import "rxjs/Rx" with capital "R" in the `SidebarService`. Otherwise, it caused me an error running angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.31 on node 7.6

Comment: In this case, how can I catch the moment when clicking outside of the sidebar and to close the sidebar?

Comment: Does it make sense to implement this pattern when one of the parts involved in the communication is itself a service? (e.g. there is a service which continuously fetches data from an HTTP API and I want it to be able to access a given component, for example to send it strings that must be showed) ...